# log4net on asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, log4net

I have an asp.net core 2.2 solution. The structure looks like
MyProject
MyProject.Web

everything is inside MyProject project and I just keep web for declarations.

I have added the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore` reference to MyProject.Web
I have added `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();` in the Startup.cs. I have also added log4net.config in the MyProject.Web and set to `Always Copy`.
I have a service in MyProject project call ServiceA

```
public class ServiceA
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public ServiceA(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    }
```

However when I run the solution it crashes with error `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`. 
When I remove ILogger from constructor of ServiceA the project runs. Anything else I am missing here?

Comment: If you use Dependency injection you should accept `ILogger<ServiceA>` as a parameter, not `ILogger`. Otherwise the DI container will try to create one `ILogger` instance.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? What exception did you get? I've made the same mistake several times but I can't remember what the exception was. I think it was that the DI container couldn't find an ILogger instance. Which makes sense, since the extensions register a strongly typed factory themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject a strongly-typed logger instead :

```
public class ServiceA
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ServiceA(ILogger<ServiceA> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

This is the simple scenario shown in [the documentation too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-logs). The docs show that the target type is used as the category name for the logger :

> Get an ILogger object from DI.

Using a controller's type name as

I've made the same mistake from time to time, but I can't remember what the exception is. If I remember correctly, it's that the DI container can't find an ILogger instance. Which makes sense, since the extensions [register a strongly typed logger](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L42). The source code for `AddLogging` contains this line:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

As the [ILogger< TCategoryName>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) docs explain, this is used to create named loggers based on a type name instead of a string:

> A generic interface for logging where the category name is derived from the specified TCategoryName type name. Generally used to enable activation of a named [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from dependency injection.)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I wasn't injecting T in logger.